# How to show output on output tab instead of terminal?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Can anyone help me with my vscode output terminal? It is not showing output in the output tab but it is showing it on the terminal and the output is empty. Can anyone help to fix this problem?

I want my output in the output tab but it is showing in the terminal

```
PS E:\coursera\front-end-development\Javascript> node "e:\coursera\front-end-development\Javascript\console.js"
Hello World!
```

Comment: why do u want to do that? also [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: is this running a launch config? (if so, show launch.json) or a task? (if so, show tasks.json).

Answer (score 0):

The default output of vscode is in **TERMINAL**. If you have additional requirements, you can install the [**Code Runner**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. After the installation is complete, use `Run Code` to run the script, and the code will be output on the **OOUTPUT** panel.

[image]

Adding the following configuration can eliminate extra information

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

[image]